# Ionic 4 Custom splashsceen

Tags: ionic4

I need to know in ionic 4 How can we create Animated Splashscreen ? In ionic 3 there are many tutorials but they are not working in ionic4 . Any one have any tutorial or any example ? Thanks

Comment: hey, can you help elaborate what does it mean the Ionic 3 guides do not work? Animated splash screen in many guides is just the first page that gets loaded as splash screen and gets dismissed once main page resources are ready. So what prevents creating same for Ionic 4 in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option for this is to use Adobe After Effects to create an animation.

You can export it into a special format and load it with Lottie.

Lottie is a library that is released by AirBnb which will load AE animations after they have been converted to json with another tool:

- https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/

You can get the Ionic Native plugin here:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/lottie-splash-screen